# Hapi.js file upload how do I grab the file so I could use imageMagick command line tool on it

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdf, asyncfileupload, hapi.js

I changed the code to output a file instead of a stream. IT provides me the the tmp path and when I use fs.readFile the data when converted to string is

```
fileUpload=Resume_BrianInoa.pdf
```

I am posting a file to hapijs server this is my route handling the post:

```
  server.route({
   method: 'POST',
   path: '/convert',
   config: {
        payload: {
           output:'file',
           maxBytes:209715200,
            parse: false,
            allow: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        },
        handler:function (request, reply) {

           console.log('path : ' + request.payload.path);
         //   request.payload["fileUpload"].pipe(fs.createWriteStream("test"));
             fs.readFile(request.payload.path, function (err, data) {
                if(err)
                   console.error(err);
                else
                   console.log(data.toString());
               // I want to rewrite the file to a new folder here 
               // Then convert it using imageMagick's command line tool
               //  var newPath = __dirname + "/uploads/" + "newFile.txt" ;
               //  fs.writeFile(newPath, data, function (err) {
               //    console.log(err);
               //    reply('done');
               //  });

             });
          }
   },
```

This is my request.payload

```
path : /tmp/1415580285921-24240-2cc7987f4fd124ac
```

I actually checked my /tmp/ folder and opened it the only thing that the file

/tmp/1415580285921-24240-2cc7987f4fd124ac

has is fileUpload=Resume_BrianInoa.pdf
The file does not get uploaded correctly

html code for my form

```
<form action="./convert" method="post">
<input type="file" name="fileUpload" id="fileUpload" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-control">
<button class="btn">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: how are you uploading the file ?
it seems like its not being uploaded and your only sending the file name to the server.

also if you disable parsing as you did you would have to parse the request yourself before you can access the file data.
you'd probably be better with leaving parsing on and accessing the file once it uploaded with
`request.payload.fileUpload.path`

Comment: I am using a simple form 

   <form action="./convert" method="post">
                     <input type="file" name="fileUpload" id="fileUpload" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-control">
                     <button class="btn">Submit</button>
                  </form>

to upload the file with enctype specified convert has a post route and is handling the file in the above code.

Comment: move the enctype into the form tag
<form action="./convert" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 

and don't disable parsing, just use `request.payload.fileUpload.path`

Comment: I did what you said and now I just get a statusCode 415 unsupported media type. Does it have to do with the payload accept property?

Comment: Ignore my last comment the accept parameter should affect the request mime type and not the actual mime of the file being sent so you can try and set the `accept` to `'multipart/form-data'` if you want to only allow it but I think it should be safe to leave it at the default

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just to sum it up your html should be something like this -

```
<form action="./convert" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="fileUpload" id="fileUpload" class="form-control"> 
    <button class="btn">Submit</button>
</form>
```

and your hapi route

```
   server.route({
       method: 'POST',
       path: '/convert',
       config: {
            payload: {
               output: 'file',
               maxBytes: 209715200,
               //allow: 'multipart/form-data',
               parse: true //or just remove this line since true is the default
            },
            handler:function (request, reply) {   
               console.log('fileUpload path : ' + request.payload.fileUpload.path);
            }
       },
   });
```

Comment: sweet okay now request.payload.fileUpload.path has data.
Do you know what my next step to converting this pdf file to png would be?

I know how to move the file over to a directory I want.
But don't know how to call a command line untility I have installed from my node app.